# How can you specify custom Environment Variables for AWS Runtime Interface Emulator for Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, environment-variables, emulation

I am creating a Java Lambda application deployed in a docker image and using the AWS runtime interface emulator to test locally. I have found documentation for using custom environment variables in the lambda console , but can not find out how to use with the (RIE). I would like to store file paths , etc in the variables. Any help is appreciated.

thank you,